# How to add a text format in text view (e.g - meaning: jdfhjds ,here meaning should always be displayed with every word)

Tags: objective-c

meaning is the text format which i want to display but getting an error.
Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    UIButton *del_btn =[[UIButton alloc] init];
    [del_btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    del_btn.frame = CGRectMake(30, 0, 35, 35);
    UIBarButtonItem *del_btn1 =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:del_btn];
    [del_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = del_btn1;
    [self getListData];
    // word.text = [word ];
    //meaning.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Meaning: %@",[]];
```

Comment: Assuming `meaning` here is a `UITextView`, can you please explain what is the error that you are seeing here?

Comment: Actually i have a text field that i need to display the meaning of the word and it should look like(meaning:hgdjksa) .Here the word after colon can be changed but meaning can't be changed.Pls help

Comment: I see. This is fairly simple. Please see my edited response.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use `NSAttributedString`.

Also, [this link](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/) would explain in length on how to format text inside `UITextView`.

**EDIT: Post OP clarification:**

This is how you will do it.

```
NSArray *test = @[@"str1", @"str2", @"str3"];
NSString *cellString = [test componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
self.meaningTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Meaning : %@", cellString];
```

Comment: U are not getting my point . i want to display (meaning :) and the word after colon is being passed from another controller . The answer u send me will print the exact string that i mentioned u in last reply

Comment: :). No, I got you. Here, you can replace test with whatever data you are getting from another view controller. Its just matter of replacing `test` here with your object containing the right data. Let me know if there is some gap here.

Comment: In my example I assumed you would replace `test` with string coming from another view controller.

Comment: there are several strings passing from another controller and everything it will changed.

Comment: Are you getting array of strings or one string after the other? Can you please share an example of data coming from another view controller. That would really help crack this :).

Comment: the view from where data is passing having table view cells containing (meaning :hdjsd,here hdjsd are array of strings which is changing and when we clicked on that cell it will navigate to other controller having a text view and i want to display that on it .now i am getting only the string after colon not meaning:.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89806/discussion-between-abhinav-and-asheesh).

Answer (score 0):

You can try by other way after replacing the substring from a string like this

```
NSString* preText = @"Meaning : hgdjksa";
NSString* newText = [preText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"hgdjksa" withString:@"newText"];
NSLog("This is your text: %@", newText);
```

Try `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`.